# Using custom NSValueTransformer subclass with bindings and reverseTransformedValue method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing a Cocoa App using Bindings. I have a NSSlider as well as a NSTextField.

Whereas the Slider's value is bound to the value returned by the transformedValue method, the TextBox should be bound to the reverseTransformedValue method.

How may I achieve this? For the Slider I entered the name of the NSValueTransformer subclass into the Value / Value Transformer Section of the Bindings tab. But how may I tell the TextFields Value Transformer section to use the reverseTransformedValue of the class?

My class implementation looks like this:
    @implementation IntegerBy1002FloatTransformer

```
-(BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation{
    return YES;
}

-(id)transformedValue:(id)value{
    float floatValue;
    int integerValue;

    /* sanity checks omitted */
    integerValue=(int)[value integerValue];
    floatValue=(float)integerValue/100.0;
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat: floatValue];
}

-(id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value{
    float floatValue;
    int integerValue;

    /* sanity checks omitted */
    floatValue=[value floatValue];
    integerValue=(int)(floatValue*100.0);
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt: integerValue];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few items of concern with your code considering the goals you mentioned and in general. There are a few things for you to reconsider regarding your overall approach.

One issue I see (that has nothing to do with your actual problem) is `-[NSNumber integerValue]` returns an `NSInteger`, not an `int`. In fact, use `NSInteger` any time you want an `int`, since the system "does the right thing" at compile time regarding 32/64-bit and other platform concerns. Same for `unsigned int` vs. `NSUInteger`. You should also probably just be using `double` and `-[NSNumber doubleValue]` instead of `float` / `-floatValue` these days if you care about precision.

Another confusing issue I see is that you're asking the number object for a floating point value, performing arithmetic, then casting the result as an integer to create a new number with the results and vice-versa. Why wouldn't you just ask for the target primitive type to begin with? Why ask for its integer value, then cast it to a `float` for floating point arithmetic when you could just ask directly for the `-floatValue`? Example:

```
return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([value floatValue] / 100.0)];
```

...and the reverse:

```
return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:([value floatValue] * 100.0)];
```

Since `NSNumber` will do the conversions for you (you can put any type of number in and get any type of number out without worry), there's no need for all this extra stuff.

But that brings me to your overall approach. As I understand it, you want your slider and text field to affect the same value, but your text field should show that value multiplied by 100, possibly formatted as an integer. If I've misunderstood your goal (which you didn't really describe - you only asked a very narrowly-focused question about a broader issue), please let me know and I'll amend my answer.

If this is what you're trying to accomplish, however, I have a few points:

1. Value transformers are two-way *for the value they're transforming, for the property to which they're bound*. That is, they take some value and transform ("translate" if you will) it one way for display and the reverse way for internal storage / setting. In your case, you only want the internally-stored value to be multiplied by 100 for display but whatever value a user types (at that magnitude) should be converted back (divided by 100) for storage if changed. Since your slider reflects the actual stored value directly, it doesn't need a value transformer.
2. The value binding here deals in `NSNumber` instances, which, as I said above, are type-agnostic internally. This means "a number is a number is a number". You can store as and retrieve as whatever primitive type you like. There's no reason to cast. I said this above but it bears repeating.
3. If you want to deal in floating points with the internal storage of the value but only allow integers in the text field's display and input, use an `NSNumberFormatter` (attach it to the text field and configure it to show only whole numbers - easily done in Interface Builder). There's no need at all to worry about what primitive type you're getting from your value because of number 2 above (ie, it's an `NSNumber`). The control (with a number formatter) takes care of that for you. It also, incidentally, enforces this on user input during editing.

With the above in mind, your value transformer methods can be greatly simplified (especially using ObjC 2.0 sweetness such as automatic number boxing and dot notation):

```
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value {
    /* sanity checks omitted */
    return @( value.doubleValue / 100.0 );
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value {
    /* sanity checks omitted */
    return @( value.doubleValue * 100.0 )
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The reason I tried this approach is, that as I understand it, NSSlider cannot take float values (I need a range of +0.5 to 4.0 with an precision of one decimal. So I thought that the internally stored value is an integer representation of the value (times 100). The slider shows the internal representation, whereas the corresponding NSTextField shows the transformed float result. Thanks for your suggestions/comments! It helped a LOT!!!

Comment: Glad that helped. Note that the slider and text field both have floatValue, doubleValue, integerValue, etc like many Cocoa controls.